# Posicionar grafico - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Gente estoy intentando colocar graficos en una interfaz de tkinter y quiero economizar el espacio de la ventana. ¿Como puedo posicionarlo por ejemplo en este caso del lado izquierdo de recuadro de la figura?
Ademas ¿Como puedo aumentar el tamaño del grafico, sin aumentar el de la figura (el recuadro blanco)? De manera que pueda reducir el tamaño de la figura sin afectar al grafico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte del codigo que genera el grafico es:

```
    Labels = 'Pendientes positivas', 'Pendientes negativas', 'Resistencias horizontales'
    sizes = [pendientes_positivas, pendientes_negativas, horizontales]
    figura, ejes = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,3), dpi = 100)
    cuñas, textos, autotextos = ejes.pie(sizes, autopct = '%1.1f%%')
    ejes.legend(cuñas, Labels, title = "Resistencias", loc = 'center left', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0, 0.5, 1))
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, frame_Resistencias_M5)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 200, y = 100)
```

Comment: Hola Caeta, no se si he entendido lo que buscas... ¿Quieres alinear la figura (grafico) a la izquierda del canvas? En vez de estar centrado como está ahora...

Comment: Tal cual, para que no me quede tanto espacio del canvas molestandome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el gráfico queda centrado en la figura sin tener en cuenta en el cálculo a la leyenda. Una posibilidad ajustar la posición de los ejes en la figura jugando con [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html):

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x500")
frame_Resistencias_M5 = tk.Frame(root)
frame_Resistencias_M5.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

pendientes_negativas = 12
pendientes_positivas = 15
horizontales = 6

labels = 'Pendientes positivas', 'Pendientes negativas', 'Resistencias horizontales'
sizes = [pendientes_positivas, pendientes_negativas, horizontales]
figura, ejes = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=100)
cuñas, textos, autotextos = ejes.pie(sizes, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ejes.legend(cuñas, labels, title="Resistencias", loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))
figura.subplots_adjust(left=0,
                       right=0.50,
                       bottom=0,
                       top=1,
                       wspace=0,
                       hspace=0
                       )
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, frame_Resistencias_M5)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=200, y=100)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]